# Windows XP - Restore Encryped File on Another computer

Tags: windows-xp

I have Windows XP systems joining Windows 2003 SBS domain. These machines contain certain folders that are encrypted using Encrypting File System (EFS).

The question is how to read encrypted files from another computer? I backup the Current User's Personal Certificate that is intended for EFS and restored it to another computer, but still can't open the encrypted file.

Recently, a system experienced corrupted user profile due to hard disk bad sector, and I have no way to recover the encrypted file.

Now I am figuring out how to backup the certificate so that I can restore the encrypted files on any computers.

Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308993